# how to enable Jetty debug log in 9.4.44 Logging initialized output (seen at INFO level)

Tags: jvm, embedded-jetty, jetty-9, ibm-jdk, j9

I am using Jetty 9.4.44 and for jetty debug logs I have added jetty-logging.properties in classpath

```
Setup logging implementation
 org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.class=org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.StdErrLog
 org.eclipse.jetty.LEVEL=INFO
 Make websocket more verbose for testing
 org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.LEVEL=DEBUG
```

After adding jetty-logging.properties file and restarting the server getting this Error

```
ALL 000000000000 GLOBAL_SCOPE 2022-04-21 01:03:42.427:DBUG:oejs.HttpChannel:qtp1984050658-1676: Could not perform ERROR dispatch, aborting
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.eclipse.jetty.server.Dispatcher (initialization failure)
        at java.lang.J9VMInternals.initializationAlreadyFailed(J9VMInternals.java:91)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler$Context.getRequestDispatcher(ContextHandler.java:2249)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ErrorHandler.doError(ErrorHandler.java:111)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ErrorHandler.handle(ErrorHandler.java:95)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.lambda$handle$3(HttpChannel.java:449)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel$$Lambda$885.00000000D40118D0.dispatch(Unknown Source)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.dispatch(HttpChannel.java:645)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:447)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:277)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:311)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:105)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$1.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:104)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.runTask(EatWhatYouKill.java:338)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.doProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:315)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.tryProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:173)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.run(EatWhatYouKill.java:131)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.ReservedThreadExecutor$ReservedThread.run(ReservedThreadExecutor.java:409)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:883)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$Runner.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:1034)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:785)
Caused by:
java.lang.NullPointerException: Logger with name [org.eclipse.jetty.server.Dispatcher]
        at java.util.Objects.requireNonNull(Objects.java:239)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.Log.getLogger(Log.java:294)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.Log.getLogger(Log.java:267)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Dispatcher.<clinit>(Dispatcher.java:45)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler$Context.getRequestDispatcher(ContextHandler.java:2249)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ErrorHandler.doError(ErrorHandler.java:111)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ErrorHandler.handle(ErrorHandler.java:95)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.lambda$handle$3(HttpChannel.java:449)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel$$Lambda$885.00000000D40118D0.dispatch(Unknown Source)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.dispatch(HttpChannel.java:645)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:447)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:277)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:311)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:105)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$1.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:104)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.runTask(EatWhatYouKill.java:338)
```

Comment: Try again with normal Java (not IBM or J9, but something from the OpenJDK family) if it works there, then you know your J9 JVM is having issues (I ask you to do this, as the J9 JVM is constantly causing problems for valid java, and has a long list of bugs unresolved).

Comment: Edit your question, and include the ["Logging initialized" output](https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/blob/jetty-9.4.44.v20210927/jetty-util/src/main/java/org/eclipse/jetty/util/log/Log.java#L170) (seen at INFO level).  This will tell us more about your logging configuration.  There might be 2 such events, one at server init, and one at webapp init.

Comment: apart from OpenJDK if there is any possibility to make working with IBM JDK?

Comment: @JoakimErdfelt or passing any  other param to make it working?

Comment: @JoakimErdfelt   I have opened a ticket with Jetty too https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/issues/7932